# Code for finding binomial coefficient in iterative form

Tags: java, recursion, iteration, binomial-coefficients

I've written the code for finding the binomial coefficient in recursive form:

```
public int binom(int n, int k)
{
    if (k==n || k==0)
        return 1;
    else return binom(n-1,k-1) + binom(n-1, k);
}
```

How can I rewrite this code in iterative form instead of recursive form?

Comment: This is easy to find with a browser search.  k!(n-k)! / n!

Comment: But I want to specifically avoid the formula (n,k) = n!/k!(n-k)!. I want to use the formula (n,k) = (n-1,k-1) + (n-1,k) instead. Is that possible?

Comment: check here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-9-binomial-coefficient/

Comment: I understand: you want an iterative implementation of the recursive formula.  @nagendra547's link has that for you.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of building the *entire* Pascal triangle up to the n-th row (memory usage grows quadratically with n), we can simply focus on the row itself, and use *constant* memory.

Let's find a relationship between consecutive terms on the same row on Pascal's triangle:

[image]

Thus we can iteratively generate the terms from <sup>n</sup>C<sub>0</sub> = 1:

```
public static int binom(int n, int k)
{
    int value = 1;
    // need to be careful here - can't just use *= due to integer division
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        value = (value * (n - i)) / (i + 1);
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int binom(int n, int k)
    {
        int C[][] = new int[n+1][k+1];
        int i, j;
        int min;

        // Caculate value of Binomial Coefficient in bottom up manner
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            min = (i<k)? i: k;

            for (j = 0; j <= min; j++)
            {
                // Base Cases
                if (j == 0 || j == i)
                    C[i][j] = 1;

                    // Calculate value using previosly stored values
                else
                    C[i][j] = C[i-1][j-1] + C[i-1][j];
            }
        }

        return C[n][k];
    }
```